# Finding the locus represented by complex variable equations?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

I'm trying to solve these two problems related to complex number but hardly found a solution.
I hope that someone can solve these and clear it up for me. Thank you.

1. |z+2|=2|z-1|
2. |z+5|-|z-5|=6

Comment: The first says $(x+2)^2+y^2=4((x-1)^2+y^2)$. Can you simplify and identify? The second is also after some simplification part of something familiar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first question was essentially answered in a comment: the locus is a circle.

So we deal with the second question. Consider the equation
$$|z+5|-|z-5|=6.\tag{1}$$
Flip it over. We get
$$\frac{1}{|z+5|-|z-5|}=\frac{1}{6}.$$
Multiply top and bottom by $|z+5|+|z-5|$. Setting $z=x+iy$, and simplifying a bit, we get 
$$|z+5|+|z-5|=\frac{10x}{3}.\tag{2}$$
Note that this forces $x$ to be positive. Now "add" (1) and (2), and simplify a bit. We get
$$|z+5|=3+\frac{5x}{3}.\tag{3}$$
Finally, replace $|z+5|$ by $\sqrt{(x+5)^2+y^2}$, and square both sides. 
It all turns out very nice, we get the equation  $\dfrac{x^2}{9}-\dfrac{y^2}{16}=1$.  **However**, we only get the right-half branch of the hyperbola, because of the positivity constraint on $x$ noted earlier.

**Remarks:** $1.$ We can also write the given equation as 
$$\sqrt{(x+5)^2+y^2}= \sqrt{(x-5)^2+y^2}+6,$$
and square both sides. We get some nice cancellation, with  a surviving "square root" term involving  $12\sqrt{(x+5)^2+y^2}$. Bring this to one side, the rest tot the other side, and square again. We end up with the equation of a hyperbola.

$2.$  One could also do it  without calculation, by recalling one definition of the hyperbola as the locus of points the *difference* of whose distances from $2$ distinct points is constant.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, This is exactly what I wanted to know. Please describe the answer one too if possible. @André Nicolas

Comment: I had done most of it in the comment. Expand $(x+2)^2+y^2=4((x-1)^2+y^2)$ and rearrange a little. We get $3x^2+3y^2-12x=0$, which simplifies to $x^2+y^2-4x=0$, or better $((x-2)^2+y^2=4$, a circle with centre $(2,0$ and radius $2$.

Comment: Thanks again, really appreciate your work. @André Nicolas

Comment: You are welcome. The calculation for the first problem is quick. You might try to do the calculation for the second problem in the style suggested in the remark. It will not be difficult, although one may miss the restriction $x\gt 0$. I did the thing in the "fancy" style above mainly for fun, and because it is a useful idea in other problems.